# No user-agent (getAgent) in filter preceding resource

Tags: java, restlet

I'm trying to extract user-agent in my custom filter:

```
public class MyFilter extends Filter {
   @Override
   protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
      String ua = request.getClientInfo().getAgent();
   }
}
```

But I always get `ua` **null**.

When the request proceeds to my `Resource`, I do manage to extract the user-agent using the call:

```
String ua = getRequest().getClientInfo().getAgent();
```

Questions:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a test of your use case with version 2.3.1 of Restlet and I can't reproduce your problem. Could you give us more hints about your context.

Here is what I used.

- **`pom.xml`**

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>restlet-user-agent</artifactId>
      <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>

      <properties>
          <java-version>1.7</java-version>
          <restlet-version>2.3.1</restlet-version>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
              <version>${restlet-version}</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>maven-restlet</id>
              <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
              <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
          </repository>
      </repositories>
  </project>
  ```
- **Filter**

  ```
  public class MyFilter extends Filter {
      public MyFilter() {
          super();
      }

      public MyFilter(Context context, Restlet next) {
          super(context, next);
      }

      public MyFilter(Context context) {
          super(context);
      }

      @Override
      protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
          String ua = request.getClientInfo().getAgent();
          System.out.println("[filter] ua = " + ua);
          return Filter.CONTINUE;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Server resource**

  ```
  public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
      @Get
      public String test() {
          String ua = getRequest().getClientInfo().getAgent();
          System.out.println("[server resource] ua = " + ua);
          return "test";
      }
  }
  ```
- **Application**

  ```
  public class RestletApplication extends Application {
      @Override
      public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          Router router = new Router(getContext());

          router.attach("/test", MyServerResource.class);
          MyFilter filter = new MyFilter(getContext(), router);
          return filter;
      }
  }
  ```

Here are the traces I got using Postman in Chrome:

```
[filter] ua = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
[server resource] ua = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
```

Hope it helps you nevertheless.
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tested now locally by myself, and it does seems to work, so it has to be some issue with my production environment... cannot pinpoint on what causes it.

Comment: works locally, but when I deploy my code to production environment, it does not work

Comment: Could you give us more details about your production environment? Is there some reverse proxies? Could you also provide us the actually request that is received by your Restlet server (once the request is passed through the different layers in front of it)? Thanks!